# WDS/MDT server - remoteinstall folder on network share or local volume?

Tags: network-share, wds, mdt, disk-volume, wim

I'd like to get this right now.

In setting up WDS, I'm getting errors pointing to a mapped network drive and I'm wondering if I should just provision a local volume for this WDS/MDT virtual machine.

Is it best practice to use a local volume and not even mess with mapped shares since with MDT I'll be sharing out the deploymentshare folder?

Thanks.

Comment: This really depends on what you plan to do with it. If you plan to replicate the deployment share across multiple locations then obviously a network share is necessary. If you are just using one server, a locally shared folder will work fine. It really doesnt matter. It all works. I’ve used a NAS before for the deployment share. You didn’t specify what trouble you are having so you may be asking the wrong questions.

Comment: I could have sworn you could have externally run the remote install folder of WDS. I'll have to test in more detail. For MDT, you can use any network share as long as it's reachable over the network and is run from SMB.

Comment: @ElliotLabsThe error message I'm getting is: "the filename, directory name, or volume syntax is incorrect."

This is a shared folder that I mapped with a drive letter. It's also not the root of the volume itself as I'm pointing to a folder inside of the mapped drive.

Does this not work with WDS, server 2016 anymore? We are running DFS but I'm not sure if that's causing an issue.